# What are the prospects of research in database field?

Tags: soft-question, ds.data-structures, db.databases

I have been working with database management systems, and would like to focus on research in this very area some day.

I was having a look at the various research labs around the world,

```
http://www-07.ibm.com/in/research/
http://research.microsoft.com
http://research.google.com/
```

but did not find any dedicated Database research groups, or any exciting activity in this area.

How do the research prospects in the Database field look like?

Comment: Nowadays, interesting Database research has morphed into areas such as data mining and information retrieval and search. Microsoft has one and they call it Information retrieval and management research area.

Comment: Googling "database research" turns up ample results, including http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/groups/db/.

Comment: I think you should do more googling. I know for a fact that the first 2 research labs you mention have dedicated database groups, and googling for "database research" and the company name comes up with them.

Answer (score 11):

As usual, to have an idea of what is happening in a field, have a look at the major conferences: [SIGMOD/PODS](http://www.sigmod.org/), [VLDB](http://www.vldb.org/), [ICDT](http://alpha.uhasselt.be/icdt/), to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

[Tokutek](http://www.tokutek.com/) is a company that sells a database management system on the backs of the [research of its founders in cache-oblivious data structures](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/cacheObliviousBTree.html).